# How to update odometer with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have figured out how to make it start at a certain number and how to smoothly transition to another number, but don't know how to increase number slowly.

The "Your heart has beaten approximately ... times in total" is a good example of what I am trying to achieve.

[Link to Odometer](http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/)

My attempt:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  odometer.innerText = 456;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!-- Odometr includes -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/odometer@0.4.8/themes/odometer-theme-car.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/odometer@0.4.8/odometer.min.js"></script>

<div id="odometer" class="odometer odometer-theme-car">123</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to increase number by one every second? what do you want to actually achieve?

Comment: Yes I want to increase the number by one every second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set 3 separate things: the duration of your animation, in both the JavaScript and CSS, and the value you want to reach.

For example, if you want to count up to ten, that should take ten seconds, per your "one number per second" request.

```
window.odometerOptions = {
  duration: 1000 // duration in milliseconds
};

setTimeout(function(){
    odometer.innerHTML = 10; // value to reach
}, 1000);
```

Then, in your CSS, override the styles.

```
// duration in seconds
.odometer.odometer-animating-up .odometer-ribbon-inner, .odometer.odometer-animating-down.odometer-animating .odometer-ribbon-inner {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 10s !important;
    -moz-transition-duration: 10s !important;
    -ms-transition-duration: 10s !important;
    -o-transition-duration: 10s !important;
    transition-duration: 10s !important
}
```

Change the math accordingly depending on your desired maximum value. If you want to keep counting up indefinitely, [look into JavaScript's setInterval() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

**Update**

Here's a simple, indefinite implementation.

```
(function() {

  // set start value
  var currentValue = 0;

  // every second, set odometer value to current value, and count up by one
  setInterval(function() { 

    odometer.innerHTML = currentValue;
    currentValue++;

  }, 1000);

})();
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer as so it counts indefinitely, I have next to zero knowledge of Javascript. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hmmm, can't seem to make it work I've put the CSS, HTML, and Javascript on this jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vc0ueqa9/1/#&togetherjs=JOu9uQS8MM) (your code is all the way at the bottom) can you try to fix it thanks.

Comment: You've modified my code. Add it as is, and let me know.

Comment: Sorry to bug ya one more time but now the CSS transitioning animation is not working. If you want I could post this as another question.